# maven doesn't pack lib to jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the next situation

```
git clone https://github.com/Ozey/telegramBot
cd telegramBot
./start.sh

and get the next error
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/bots/TelegramLongPollingBot
```

can't understand why this lib isn't in jar file

Comment: Without the appropriate pom file without any supplemental information nor a full log file it's impossible to guess what's wrong...

Comment: I think pom.xml on github looks much pretty :)
https://github.com/Ozey/telegramBot/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyFirstProject</groupId>
<artifactId>MyFirstProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyFirstProject</name>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.rubenlagus</groupId>
        <artifactId>TelegramBots</artifactId>
        <version>v2.3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>api.Test</mainClass>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin to your project pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This will copy all libraries into lib folder when you will run mvn clean install command. when you will generate final jar or war, you will get all the libraries

Comment: i've added, but it doesn't work
https://github.com/Ozey/telegramBot/blob/master/pom.xml